# Flex Mobile 4.6 StageVideo not removing from stage

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

When I instantiate a new StageVideo instsance with stage.stageVideos[0] everything works great, but when i leave my view that's displaying the video it sticks on the stage. So when i goto another view it's still showing on the stage in the background. I tried setting sv = null, removing event listeners...etc. 
I've created a StageVideoDisplay class which is instantiated in mxml like:  and on view initialization i call a play() method:

```
if ( _path )
        {
            //... 
            // Connections 
            _nc = new NetConnection(); 
            _nc.connect(null); 
            _ns = new NetStream(_nc); 
            _ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus); 
            _ns.client = this; 

            // Screen 
            _video = new Video(); 
            _video.smoothing = true;  

            // Video Events 
            // the StageVideoEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_STATE informs you whether 
            // StageVideo is available 
            stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, 
                onStageVideoState); 
            // in case of fallback to Video, listen to the VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE 
            // event to handle resize properly and know about the acceleration mode running 
            _video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, videoStateChange); 
            //... 
        }
```

On video stage event:

```
if ( stageVideoInUse ) {
            try {
                _rc = new Rectangle(0,0,this.width,this.height);
                _sv.viewPort = _rc;       
            } catch (e:Error) {}
        } else {
            try {
                _video.width = this.width;
                _video.height = this.height;
            } catch (e:Error) {}
        }
```

And on stage video availability event:

```
protected function toggleStageVideo(on:Boolean):void 
    {     
        // To choose StageVideo attach the NetStream to StageVideo 
        if (on) 
        { 
            stageVideoInUse = true; 
            if ( _sv == null ) 
            { 
                try {
                    _sv = stage.stageVideos[0]; 
                    _sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange); 
                    _sv.attachNetStream(_ns); 
                    _sv.depth = 1;
                } catch (e:Error) {}
            } 

            if (classicVideoInUse) 
            { 
                // If you use StageVideo, remove from the display list the 
                // Video object to avoid covering the StageVideo object 
                // (which is always in the background) 
                stage.removeChild ( _video ); 
                classicVideoInUse = false; 
            } 
        } else 
        { 
            // Otherwise attach it to a Video object 
            if (stageVideoInUse) 
                stageVideoInUse = false; 
            classicVideoInUse = true; 
            try {
                _video.attachNetStream(_ns); 
                stage.addChildAt(_video, 0); 
            } catch (e:Error) {}
        } 

        if ( !played ) 
        { 
            played = true; 
            _ns.play(path); 
        } 
    }
```

What happens is in the view when i navigator.popView(), the stageVideo remains on the stage, even in other views, and when returning to that view to play a different stream the same stream is kind of "burned" on top. I can not figure out a way to get rid of it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Flash Player 11, Adobe added the `dispose()` method to the `NetStream` class.

This is useful to clear the `Video` or `StageVideo` object when you're done with it.

When you call the `dispose()` method at runtime, you may get an exception indicating that there is no property named `dispose` on the `NetStream` object.

This occurs because Flash Builder is not compiling the app with the proper SWF version. To fix that, just add this to your compiler directives:

`-swf-version=13`

In the new Flash Builder 4.7, we hopefully won't have to specify the SWF version to use the newer Flash Player features.

This seems to be the best solution, but if you can't use Flash 11 (or the latest Adobe AIR),  some other work arounds would be:

- set the `viewPort` of stage video object to a rectangle that has width=0 and height=0
- since stage video appears underneath your app, you can always cover the viewport (with a background color or some `DisplayObject`)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this didn't seem to do anything. It did seem to help the video from not playing in the background when leaving the view. However, the stageVideo is still present on the stage when going to another view. Also, when moving to the same view and trying to play another video the same video is still on stage in a paused state or something just siting there on top...

Comment: Works for me on the web, I've never tried it w/AIR. Is that happening on the device and the simulator? It might be helpful to see more code, or a simple example of what you're doing. Remember, stage video is underneath your app, so as a last resort you can hide it.

Comment: Hello, Yes it is in AIR 3.3 (latest version) and on an android device. I've basically followed the tutorials and created a StageVideoDisplay class which has a play() method that does a simple net connection and net stream object. After that I just check the availability and either use a video object or the stage.stageVideos[0] object. When i hit the back button i try to null everything out and remove listeners but that doesn't really seem to do anything. On view initialize i call the play() function of the class which is instantiated in mxml <components:StageVideoDisplay />

Comment: Should I maybe be listening for the netstatus event and dispose before leaving the view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was actually that, even though it seemed like stage video was in use since i got the "Accelerated" message in status, that it was actually the video render even running and classic video was actually in use. The only thing I needed to do was add stage.removeChild( _video ) to the close() event in the class!!